# EXC_BAD_ACCESS If an error occurs, tell us how to try catch

Tags: ios, swift

```
let path = DataManager.Data.filePath
self.pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))!

self.pdfView.document = self.pdfDocument   <——— EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error on this line.
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS If an error occurs, tell us how to try catch.

It does not occur when opening all pdf files, 
but when trying to open a specific pdf file, EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs.

First, when EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs, you want to prevent app crush with try catch.

I have tried all the methods but I have not been able to catch it and I have been app crushing on that line.

What should I do..?

Comment: Is there any error message in console why it happens?

Comment: Try getting rid of forced unwrapping.

Comment: Add the crash logs and use like- if let data = self.pdfDocument {//do your stuff here }

Comment: The error log is not output.

Comment: First of all, do not name any property with capital `Data`, this could interfere with the struct `Data`. Name properties always starting with a lowercase letter to avoid unexpected behavior. Most likely the crash occurs because the URL is not valid. What does `filePath` return?

Comment: What is odd is when testing with a device and testing with a simulator. It will run normally when tested with the simulator.

Comment: The file path is output as /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A343BF55-9410-4F1E-8323-548CDF77B323/Documents/367.pdf.

Comment: PDF kit is in use.

Comment: The problem is that only certain PDF documents are generating errors. Some PDF documents open normally without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error occures because the path you are trying to pass to the pdfDocument is nil and you try to force unwrap it ,

try to use this error handling

```
let path = DataManager.Data.filePath
if let document =  PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
self.pdfView.document = document 
}
else {
 //return from function or do what ever you need if you can't get the pdf document
}
```

Comment: The path is not a nil value. However, only certain PDF files are causing problems, so I want to avoid them.

Comment: If that was the case, then `PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))!` should cause the crash, not the other line.